# Power Query Sum of column by group as new column

Tags: excel, powerquery

So I am new to power query and I just wasted over an hour looking for something that I can do easily in many other programs.

I just want to create a new column summing up another column. FOr instance, to check if the percentage a correct and if not normalize therafter. I dont want to group by and reduce the table.

[image]

I ve been searching left and right and tried to add a new column like "Group Sum" using stuff like
= list.sum([Number])
= Calculate(SUM([Number])

just to get the the total sum of all entries 200. No success.

Maybe its me, but I really dont see the logic.

I now tried

```
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
        #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"Group", type text}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Group Sum", Int64.Type}, {"Spalte1", Int64.Type}})
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Geänderter Typ","Group Sum",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Geänderter Typ", each [Group]=i[Group])[Number]), type number )
    in
        #"Geänderter Typ"
```

which results in an error and

```
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"Group", type text}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Group Sum", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte" = Table.AddColumn(#"Geänderter Typ", "Benutzerdefiniert", each Table.Group(Quelle, {"Group"}, {{"Group Sum", each List.Sum([Number]), type nullable number}}))
in
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte"
```

Which gives me a new column where all entries say "Table"

Comment: Easiest ,,, Group on column [Group] and sum column [Number]. Merge that back into original table using left outer join (the default) and expand using arrows atop the new column

Comment: First step is easy, where do I find the left outer join? Do i need to save the group by result in a different table in between?

Comment: I just want to note here this example is confusing because the group sums are the same for both groups. It means you might think something is working when it isn't.  I believe that's the case in at least one of the answers below, where it uses Table.Distinct() in part and that works only by coincidence because the group sums are the same, and so if you "pick one group sum and apply it to all groups" it looks like it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two other options. The examples assume your source table is named Table1. Here's how mine looks at its source in Excel:

[image]

Note it does *not* have a Group Sum column. The query will derive that.

**Option 1.**

Click Add Column then Custom Column and fill out the screen like this and click OK:

[image]

You should see a table like this:

[image]

Then just click the table in the first row of the Custom column and you should get a table that looks like this:

[image]

Then you can merge this new table with the original source table (Table1). Click Home > Merge Queries and fill out the information for the merge like this and click OK. (Note that the same query "Table1" is being merged to itself at this point, and only the Group column is selected for each entry.)

[image]

You should see a table like this:

[image]

Then, in the formula bar above that table, where you see `= Table.NestedJoin(Custom, {"Group"}, Custom, {"Group"}, "Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter)`, change the first instance of Custom to Source, so the line reads `= Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Group"}, Custom, {"Group"}, "Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter)` instead.

That is, change it from:

[image]

To:

[image]

Then expand the new Custom column by clicking the [image] button, only selecting the Group Sum column, clearing the checkbox beside "Use original column name as prefix," and clicking OK:

[image]

You should get this result:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group", type text}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Number", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"Group Sum", each List.Sum([Number]), type nullable number}})),
    Custom = #"Added Custom"{0}[Custom],
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Group"}, Custom, {"Group"}, "Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", {"Group Sum"}, {"Group Sum"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

(You can replace Table1, Source and Changed Type with Tablelle1, Quelle, and #"Geänderter Typ", respectively throughout the code above to align with Max's language.)

**Option 2.**

Click Transform then Group By and fill out the screen like this and click OK:

[image]

Then expand the AllData column with only the Gender and Number columns selected like this:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [Group=text, Gender=text, Number=number]}, {"Group Sum", each List.Sum([Number]), type number}}),
    #"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "AllData", {"Gender", "Number"}, {"Gender", "Number"})
in
    #"Expanded AllData"
```

Comment: Sorry I am failing at the first step I use add custom column and type in this 'Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"Group Sum", each List.Sum([Number]), type nullable number}})' and it says Expression.Error: Name source not recognized. Should I use "Tabelle1"?

Comment: I think, from your example that you provided of what you tried, you have Quelle instead of Source in your M code, so I'm thinking you should use Quelle in place of Source.

Comment: Yes I tried that but then i only get "table" in each entry

Comment: I noticed you are using your table, Tabelle1, with the Group Sum column already in it as your source. My Table1 did not include the Group Sum column since that was what I was deriving via the query. I believe having it in the source presents a conflict. I think you should delete that column from your Tabelle1 in Excel. I am going to append M code for option 1 based on your example into my answer above. I'll use Tablelle1, Quelle, and #"Geänderter Typ", so you may be able to cut and paste it directly.

Comment: I think option 1 is wrong and only appears to work because the sum is the same here for all groups.  It appears the first operation (add custom column) generates a new column that consists of a table for each row.  The tables are identical, and any one of them has the values we want.  We just need to join it onto the original table.  However, the next operation with its Table.Distinct() doesn't seem to actually do this.  It does a cartesian join and then removes duplicate rows.  With different group sums, this multiplies the dataset and does not give the desired result.

Comment: @Mark E, You are absolutely correct! Option 1 did _not_ work correctly. Based on your finding, I went back and changed it to use a merge of that table. Thank you for pointing out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let Quelle= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Quelle, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Group", type text}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Number", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Geänderter Typ","Group Sum2",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Geänderter Typ", each [Group]=i[Group]) [Number]), type number )
in #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Group and Join Method**

I have now seen a few ways to do this, but I think the most efficient is probably a group-and-join approach that builds on previous comments and answers here.  It takes one line:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.Join(Source, "Group", Table.Group(Source,{"Group"},{{"Group Sum", each List.Sum([Number]), type nullable number}}), "Group")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

The Table.Group() part of this creates a table with each unique value of the grouping variable ("Group" here) and, for each of those unique values, its summary value (the sum of [Number] for all rows with the same "Group" value here).  To attach these summary values onto the original table becomes the job for Table.Join(). The Table.Join() function gets four input arguments: 1.) the original table, 2.) the grouping column in the original table ("Group" here), 3.) the summary table (that's the output of the Table.Group() function here) and 4.) the grouping column in summary table (also "Group" here).

I tested this and get the results as shown:

[image]

Note: I changed Number column values from the question to show that the code is working.  In the example provided in the original question, the Group Sum is 100 for both groups, and that seems to make the approach suggested in another answer look like it's working when it does not.